# Cómo obtener un propiedad de algún objeto que están dentro de un array

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo una función `estado` que recibe como argumento un array de objetos llamado `usuarios` y un **string** llamada `nombre`.

Cada objeto tiene dos propiedades. Una llamada `nombre` que es un **string** y la otra llamada `enlinea` que es un **booleano**.

La función debe **retornar true** si el usuario se encuentra enlinea, si no se cumple debe **retornar false**.

Ejemplo:

```js
var usuarios = [
    {nombre: 'ana',enlinea: true},
    {nombre: 'maca',enlinea: true},
    {nombre: 'lore',enlinea: false}
    ];

estado(usuarios, 'ana') retorna true
estado(usuarios, 'lore') retorna false
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu caso, para acceder a una propiedad de un objeto que está dentro de un array, deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```
var usuarios = [{nombre: 'ana',enlinea: true},{nombre: 'maca',enlinea: true},{nombre: 'lore',enlinea: false}];
console.log(usuarios[0].nombre)
//devolvería 'ana'
```

De la misma manera para acceder a la segunda posición del array deberías poner `usuarios[1]` seguido de`.nombre_propiedad`.

Answer (score 0):

Excelente, entonces me quedaría así:

```js
let usuarios = [{nombre: 'toni',enlinea: true},{nombre: 'montana',enlinea: true},{nombre:'james',enlinea: false},{nombre: 'bond',enlinea: false}];
function estado(usuarios,nombre){
  let recorrer = usuarios
                  .filter(usuarios => usuarios.nombre == nombre)
                  .map(usuarios => usuarios.enlinea).toString()
  console.log(recorrer);
}
estado (usuarios,"james"); //false
```

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Soy consciente de que esta es una pregunta antigua, pero creo que la solución a la misma se puede mejorar y ser de más utilidad para futuros lectores.

Si se tiene una matriz de objetos, como esta:

```
let usuarios =
[
    { nombre: 'Ana',  enLinea: true  },
    { nombre: 'Maca', enLinea: true  },
    { nombre: 'Lore', enLinea: false }
];
```

Y se desea que una función determine el estatus de un usuario en específico, determinado por su nombre, un perfecto enfoque sería una búsqueda secuencial.

En [este artículo](https://medium.com/laboratoria-developers/algoritmos-de-b%C3%BAsqueda-en-javascript-6c55e8ca5d19) se puede encontrar información más detallada sobre diversos algoritmos de búsqueda en JavaScript y, en el mismo se explica lo siguiente:

> Llamamos búsqueda secuencial a aquella en la que comparamos cada elemento del vector con el valor a buscar y, en caso de una coincidencia, detenemos el ciclo o iterador usado para recorrer nuestro vector y retornamos o utilizamos dicha coincidencia.

Existen varias formas de implementarlo, pero acá dejo algunos ejemplos:

- Búsqueda sencuencial empleando un ciclo `for` clásico:

```js
let usuarios =
[
    { nombre: 'Ana',  enLinea: true  },
    { nombre: 'Maca', enLinea: true  },
    { nombre: 'Lore', enLinea: false }
];

function estaEnLinea(usuarios, nombre)
{
    for (let i = 0; i < usuarios.length; i++)
    {
        if (usuarios[i].nombre === nombre)
        {
            return usuarios[i].enLinea;   
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}

console.log('Ana en línea: ',  estaEnLinea(usuarios, 'Ana'));
console.log('Lore en línea: ', estaEnLinea(usuarios, 'Lore'));
```

- Búsqueda sencuencial empleando un ciclo `for` de iteración:

```js
let usuarios =
[
    { nombre: 'Ana',  enLinea: true  },
    { nombre: 'Maca', enLinea: true  },
    { nombre: 'Lore', enLinea: false }
];

function estaEnLinea(usuarios, nombre)
{
    for (let usuario of usuarios)
    {
        if (usuario.nombre === nombre)
        {
            return usuario.enLinea;   
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}

console.log('Ana en línea: ',  estaEnLinea(usuarios, 'Ana'));
console.log('Lore en línea: ', estaEnLinea(usuarios, 'Lore'));
```

- Empleando el método [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) y, opcionalmente para navegadores más modernos los operadores: [`Operador de coalescencia nula (??)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing)(documentado en inglés) y [`Operador de encadenamiento opcional (?.)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```js
let usuarios =
[
    { nombre: 'Ana',  enLinea: true  },
    { nombre: 'Maca', enLinea: true  },
    { nombre: 'Lore', enLinea: false }
];

function estaEnLinea(usuarios, nombre)
{
    let usuario = usuarios.find(u => u.nombre === nombre);
    
    if (usuario)
    {
        return usuario.enLinea;
    }
    
    return false;
    
    // O en navegadores más modernos:
    // return usuario?.enLinea ?? false;
}

console.log('Ana en línea: ',  estaEnLinea(usuarios, 'Ana'));
console.log('Lore en línea: ', estaEnLinea(usuarios, 'Lore'));
```

- Empleando [`Array.prototype.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) (¿Porqué no?):

```js
let usuarios =
[
    { nombre: 'Ana',  enLinea: true  },
    { nombre: 'Maca', enLinea: true  },
    { nombre: 'Lore', enLinea: false }
];

function estaEnLinea(usuarios, nombre)
{
    let indice = usuarios.findIndex(u => u.nombre === nombre);

    return usuarios[indice].enLinea;
}

console.log('Ana en línea: ',  estaEnLinea(usuarios, 'Ana'));
console.log('Lore en línea: ', estaEnLinea(usuarios, 'Lore'));
```

Existen más formas de lograrlo, pero agregarlas sería extender innecesariamente demasiado esta respuesta.